# SSH works on two servers, but can't SSH to each other

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have two Ubuntu servers on my network. I can ssh to both of them from my workstation, but can't ssh from one server to the other. I even stopped ufw on both servers to see if that was the case and checked deny hosts.

When attempting to ssh from [a] to [b], it hangs for a while and then gives a timeout notice.

```
eric@[a]:~$ ssh -vvv [b]:22
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: Applying options for * 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Deprecated option "FallBackToRsh" 
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0 
ssh: [b]:22: Name or service not known
```

Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting? I need to be able to connect these servers together so I can setup rsync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ssh -vvv [b]:22

That is the wrong syntax.  SSH doesn't accept ports as `:22` after the hostname.  Use -p to specify a port, or don't pass anything since port 22 is the default.

Your system is trying to resolve the name `[b]:22` which doesn't exist. since presumably your host is named `[b]`.

Comment: Yes, [b] is the server name. it doesn't matter if I don't give a port number or apply -p to specify the port. All three variations result in the same message.

Comment: Obviously you are doing something wrong, but your obfuscation of the command, and the output is almost certainly hiding the actual problem.  If you get a `Name or service not known`, then you know it tried to resolve the name you with DNS, and the name could not be resolved.  I suspect if you want help you are going to have to post the un-obfuscated command you are using and the output.

Comment: eric@cis:~$ ssh -vvv 10.105.2.220
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Deprecated option "FallBackToRsh"
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.105.2.220 [10.105.2.220] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.105.2.220 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.105.2.220 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Well, that is the same error.  That is `Connection timed out` error, not `Name or service not known` message, so the output **IS** different.  Can you actually ping the server IP from the client?

Comment: Hmmm. No, and I disabled the firewall on both sides. sudo ufw disable : but I can get to both machines from a different machine on the same network. I verified there are no entries in deny hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Its saying you cant resolve [b], try sshing with the IP address.

Comment: I tried that as well, can't SSH to the IP address either. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: the error you have provided points to a problem with name resolution, try it with the IP address and post the output of ssh -vv that if its different.

Comment: Same result using the ip address and ssh -vv instead of -vvv

Comment: Using an IP address with the correct port syntax (as in the other answer) can't be giving you the same name resolution error. Get the actual output from 'ssh -vvv ip.for.host.b` please.

Comment: eric@cis:~$ ssh -vvv 10.105.2.220
    OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Deprecated option "FallBackToRsh"
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 10.105.2.220 [10.105.2.220] port 22.
    debug1: connect to address 10.105.2.220 port 22: Connection timed out
    ssh: connect to host 10.105.2.220 port 22: Connection timed out